# Confirming reset password using jsonwebtoken and nodejs

Tags: node.js, json, express

I am having a difficult way figuring out the best way to get this validation for resetting a password. I am wanting to remove the option of the user typing in their username. I had tried to use this option as a way to query the database to check for the token again since I was using a post request but if the user tries to spray usernames, it would crash the application because in my database, I have the link being saved as null first, and then when they request to the reset link, I save it to the database but the link is valid for only 5 minutes and I have a rate limiter on these request as well. Would a GET request be the better way since I can get the token again? If so, how would I get the token again using two get request? below the backend and frontend.

BACKEND

```
resetPasswordController.js

const reset_password_index = async (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.params;
  if (!token) {
    req.flash("error", "The link you clicked on is invalid.")
    res.redirect("/")
    return;
  } else {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decodedData) => {
      if (!err) {
        const error = req.flash().error || [];
        res.render("reset-password", { token, error });
      } else {
        res.send(
          "There was an error with the link. Please request another one."
        );
      }
    });
  }
};

const reset_password_validation = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, newPassword, confirmedPassword } = req.body;
  let query = await User.findOne({ username: username });
  // CHECK FOR USERNAME SPRAY & MISMATCH PASSWORD
  jwt.verify(query.resetlink, process.env.JWT_SECRET, async (err, decodedData) => {
    if (!decodedData) {
      req.flash("error", err);
      res.redirect(`/reset-password/${query.resetlink}`);
    } else if (newPassword !== confirmedPassword) {
      req.flash("error", "PASSWORDS DO NOT MATCH");
      res.redirect(`/reset-password/${query.resetlink}`);
    } else {
      try {
        let savedUser = await query.setPassword(newPassword);
        await savedUser.save();
        req.flash("success", "Password was successfully changed. Please login");
        res.redirect("/login");
      } catch (error) {
        req.flash(
          "error",
          "There was an error updating your password please try again."
        );
        res.redirect(`/reset-password/${query.resetlink}`);
      }
    }
  });
};

module.exports = {
  reset_password_index,
  reset_password_validation,
};
```

FRONTEND

```
           <form action="/reset-password/validation" method="post">
              <div class="input-group flex-nowrap mb-4">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping"
                  >Username</span
                >
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="username"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Enter Email Address"
                  aria-label="Enter user name"
                  aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div class="input-group flex-nowrap mb-4">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping"
                  >New Password</span
                >
                <input
                  type="password"
                  id="newPassword"
                  name="newPassword"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="New Password"
                  aria-label="something@email.com"
                  aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
                  required
                />
              </div>
              <div class="input-group flex-nowrap mb-4">
                <span class="input-group-text" id="addon-wrapping"
                  >Confirm Password</span
                >
                <input
                  type="password"
                  id="confirmedPassword"
                  name="confirmedPassword"
                  class="form-control"
                  placeholder="Confirm Password"
                  aria-label="something@email.com"
                  aria-describedby="addon-wrapping"
                  required
                />
                <span id="message"></span>
              </div>
              <div class="d-grid col-5 mx-auto">
                <button
                  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                  type="submit"
                  role="button"
                >
                  Update password
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround. By templating the decode webtoken into the button value, I was able to grab it from the body on submit, and then query based off that. Below is the code for those who will see it later and wanted to see a way of doing it outside of MERN MEAN stacks.

BACKEND

```
resetPasswordController.js
const reset_password_index = async (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.params;
  if (!token) {
    req.flash("error", "The link you clicked on is invalid.")
    res.redirect("/")
    return;
  } else {
    jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decodedData) => {
      if (!err) {
        let verifiedUser = decodedData.id
        const error = req.flash().error || [];
        res.render("reset-password", { token, error, username:verifiedUser });
      } else {
        res.send(
          "There was an error with the link. Please request another one."
        );
      }
    });
  }
};

const reset_password_validation = async (req, res) => {
  const { username, newPassword, confirmedPassword } = req.body;
  let query = await User.findOne({ username: username })
  // CHECK FOR USERNAME SPRAY & MISMATCH PASSWORD
  jwt.verify(query.resetlink, process.env.JWT_SECRET, async (err) => {
    if (err) {
      req.flash("error", err);
      res.redirect(`/reset-password/${query.resetlink}`);
    } else if (newPassword !== confirmedPassword) {
      req.flash("error", "PASSWORDS DO NOT MATCH");
      res.redirect(`/reset-password/${query.resetlink}`);
    } else {
      try {
        let savedUser = await query.setPassword(newPassword);
        await savedUser.save();
        req.flash("success", "Password was successfully changed. Please login");
        res.redirect("/login");
      } catch (error) {
        req.flash(
          "error",
          "There was an error updating your password please try again."
        );
        res.redirect(`/reset-password/${query.resetlink}`);
      }
    }
  });
};
```

FRONTEND

```
<div class="d-grid col-5 mx-auto">
                <button
                  class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"
                  type="submit"
                  name="username"
                  //THIS IS THE VALUE FROM THE TOKEN BEING PASSED IN MUST BE IN VALUE
                  value="<%=username%>"
                >
                  Update password
                </button>
              </div>
```